# errExit not available in CLion?

Tags: unix, posix, system, exit

I am trying to use errExit function on CLion IDE but it seems gives this error.
"cant resolve errExit variable" . I cant find anything about it,which header to use? I simply use text book example and included all headers from there still nothing?

Comment: Which book? Just use `exit` or similar http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit

Comment: Linux System Programming 2010 edition Beginning Linux Programming, 4 Editio

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing these error messages, because `errExit` is not a standard API function.

The **camelCaseNotation** is a good indicator of this. As a rule of thumb, the standard bodies of POSIX, UNIX and BSD -- which define most of the standard utilities and functions present on conforming GNU/Linux systems today -- specify functions using **underscore_notation**.

My guess is that the authors of the books you follow provide a definition for that function for their readers to use. Try looking for it in an earlier chapter, in the index, or in the supplementary material. But you won't find it in the systems standard include files.